# Excel: select column in range by column index - no vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell A1, and then below 4 columns. Cell A1 right now contains number 2.

```
2 

|  A   |  B   |  C   | SELECTED |
|  12  |  44  |  88  | 44       |
|  43  |  55  |  99  | 55       |
|  54  |  66  |  11  | 66       |
```

Which formula should I put into 'Selected' column to display there values of the second column? I would like the A1 cell to control which values are displayed there. Basically, I'm looking for a similar functionality to a VLOOKUP, except there is no lookup and it just takes range a4:c4 and selectes column number A1.

Comment: Use the **INDEX()** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDEX()` for that. Let's say that `12`, `44` and `88` are in columns A, B and C respectively, and on row 4.

In the first cell under `SELECTED`, you can put this:

```
=INDEX(A4:C4, 0, A$1)
```

And then you can drag this down to get the remaining rows.

`INDEX` takes the whole row (hence the `0`) and the column from the value in `A$1` from the range `A4:C4`.

Answer (score 1):

In **D2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:C,ROW(),$A$1)
```

and copy down